# Best practice to manage content source and crawling on VM

Tags: search, crawling

I am using SP2013 standard and have two web applications. One app (`http://blog.domain.com` solely for My Site Host) and another app (`http://web.domain.com`) for the other type of site collections.

I follow [this MSDN article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn535606.aspx#BKMK_CrawlUserProfiles) to setup two content sources:

People: `sps3://blog.domain.com`

Local SharePoint sites: `http://blog.domain.com` and `http://web.domain.com`

"People" take less than 30 min to complete full crawl and "Local SharePoint sites" takes 6 hours for my first trial but then never completes again after I needed to reconfigure something (I just installed some language packs).

My questions are:

1. I am using a VM for my developing. When I am back to office and start the crawl, the crawling requires so much time that I actually have to leave the office and shut down the guest pc before the process ends. So I "pause" the crawling and suspend the VM. Then I will resume it next day. Today it take another 6 hours and I have to pause it again. Will it cause problem? Actually... in production environment, if full crawling still in process, I should never touch it? Otherwise I have to start all over again?
2. Should I break the "Local Sharepoint sites" sources to two? So that one is crawling `blog.domain.com` and one for `web.domain.com`. Will it enhance performance? Will it effect the search result in Search Center?

Comment: Is this a single box VM? Describe the topology for the farm. Also, what resources and how much content. In my demo I have about 100MB content and with 12GB RAM and 2 cores on my SharePoint box I crawl it in about 8 minutes.

Comment: Matthew, 8 min is really impressive. Are you using SSD?
My VM box is an all-in-one: Sharepoint, DC, SQL2008 are installed in same VM box. Search components are residented on the box, too. I have about 100MB content and the VM is assigned with 4GB ram. Host running Core i7 cpu.

Comment: Wow, with that configuration 4GB is WAY too low. You should look at a minimum of 12GB if not 16GB RAM. I have 3-5 separate VMs depending on my needs. Yes, dual SSDs with seperate drives for the SharePoint and SQL Vms.

Comment: Style here is you buy your own tool for work and I only have a 8GB notebook on hand. BTW, I have tried pause the crawling and continue in next day. The crawling is finally completed after 13hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managing Search on a development machine can be a challenge. One approach is to only maintain a representative amount of content so that you can do the needed development without suffering long crawl times. In a development environment you need RAM and fast disks.

1. In production you will either use continuous crawling or create scheduled crawl times. Either way, ideally, you don't mess with the crawls in production.
2. Splitting them won't necessarily enhance the crawl times, adding more crawl components will, to a point. One reason to split them is for scheduling purposes. The search center will be unaffected by the split.